# Ajax call POST method, object update with data in success handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise

I would like to update the main object with data in success handler and while next ajax call is being made I want to post with updated object.

```
var getValue = function() {
  var mainObject = {
    "name": "Tom",
    "age": 26
  }
  return mainObject;
}

var setValue = {
  "detailsMethod": {
    var sendObject = getValue();
    $.ajax({
      url: 'https://....',
      data: sendObject
    })
    .success(function(data) {
        var location = data.name
        var sendValue = getValue();
        sendValue.location = location; // when the next Ajax call is being made add location value to mainObject
    })
    .error(function() {
      //Error
    })
  }
}

setValue.detailsMethod();
```

Comment: There are a lot of things wrong in this code.... That code is not making the Ajax call, it is throwing an error. You have an object that is not valid and you treat it like it is a function. When you do get it to run by defining the object you return an object and set the location property on it, but that is not going to do anything.

Comment: how to add value to the mainObject from success and post the updatedObject..during next ajax call

Comment: Every time you call `getValue()` it's creating and returning a different object.

Comment: You need to use a global variable to hold an object that persists from one call to the next.

Comment: The value assigned to `window.onload` needs to be a function. You're calling the function immediately, not assigning a reference to the function. Take off the `()` at the end.

Comment: I have created a global variable but it is not availabile since the ajax call is being made on page load

Answer (score 0):

This version should actually work, however i'm not sure if this is what you want.

```js
var mainObject = {
  "name": "Tom",
  "age": 26
};

function updateValue() {
  $.ajax({
      url: 'https://....',
      data: mainObject
    })
    .success(function(data) {
      mainObject.name = data.name;
    })
    .error(function() {
      //Error
    })
}

window.onload = updateValue;
```

on load, updateValue gets called and an ajax request gets made. When the response arrives, the mainObject gets updated with the response data.